# search string preceded by either a space or a slash

Tags: regex, grep

I've files with below content:

```
76a6f0f631888fbd359420796093d19a3928123d remotes/origin/feature/ASC-122356
417435aceb671e41213697055b86d860d9a9a61c remotes/origin/feature/ASC-122356-3762
ae863a41fef068215be1529216e9dbba1314fa6f remotes/origin/master
```

I want to search if `origin/master` pattern is there or not in the file.

I'm currently doing like `grep -e '^\S\+ origin/master$'` but it's not correct. How can I do it?

Comment: The ultimate problem is you are searching for `origin/master` preceded with and empty space, but the example file does not contain any such line. Elaborate whether the `origin/master` needs to be _contained_ in the second column, or the second column must be _equal to_ `origin/master`.

Comment: @OliverGondža ```origin/master``` needs to be *contained* in the second column, may or may not preceded with white space. I need to handle both case I believe

Comment: @oguzismail this one worked.Thanks

Comment: @oguzismail you can do that

Comment: How about: `grep -e '\borigin/master\b' file`

Answer (score -1):

The pattern is uses '^\S+ ' to request that ALL characters before origin/master will be non-space (because of the '^').

Consider using similar version, which will ask for ONE space

```
grep -e ' \S\+origin/master$'
```

Comment: I don't want to check for white space before ```origin/master```. In the example as we can see in the file the ```origin/master``` in succeeded with *remotes*, in that case also it should return it

Comment: Pattern revised t eliminate excess space

Answer (score -1):

Following would work with grep. Positive number of non-space characters, followed by a space, followed by a possibly empty sequence of non-space characters and followed by the expected string.

```sh
grep -P '\S+ \S*origin/master$' test
```

Can be improved to make sure the `origin` is either at the begining of the second column or preceded by a `/` to eliminate strings like `remotes/backup-origin/master`

```sh
grep -P '^\S+ (|\S*/)origin/master$' test
```

Note those expressions require (`-P`) - perl compatible regexes.